# Change opacity of background when modal open (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to change the opacity of a background for a specific modal #vmodal, I do not want to change the opacity for other modals.

Here is what I tried, but it does not change anything...

```
#vmodal .modal-backdrop.show {
    opacity: 0.85;
}
```

If I remove #vmodal, it changes all the modals, not just this specific one.

Comment: This code can't work `.modal-backdrop` is outside of modal. You have to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

You must have a div for your backgroud apps, and your modal must not be include in this one. Like

```
<div id="main-apps"> ......
</div>
<div id="vmodal"> ......
</div>
```

when you open your modal run this javascript :

```
$('#main-apps').css({'opacity': 0.5,'z-index': 5,'pointer-events': 'none' });
```

and this when you close your modal

```
$('#main-apps').css({'opacity': 1,'z-index': 'auto','pointer-events': 'all' });
```